# Checking for error when using the PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER macro

Tags: c++, pthreads

As a rule, I was told that any system call (or alike) should be tested for errors on return.

When initializing a pthread mutex using:

```
pthread_mutex_t myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

We don't check wether the operation was successful or not.

But using this macro instead of dynamic initialization seems to be a common practice.

Is there any good reason an error check isn't needed in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason error checking isn't necessary is because static
initialization cannot fail.  In the most common implementations,
`PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` will be something along the lines of
`0` or `{}` (depending on how `pthread_mutex_t` is defined), to
ensure zero initialization, and the the various system calls
which use the `pthread_mutex_t` are designed to treat a zero
initialized `pthread_mutex_t` as if it had been initialized to
all default values, either because the type was designed
explicitly this way, or because the routines use lazy
initialization.

(Note that `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` cannot be anything along
the lines of `__special_mutex_initializer()`, since it can be
used to initialize file scope static variables in C, and
C requires compile time constant expressions for the
initialization of static variables.)

EDIT:

For more information, you might want to read the rationale
section of
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html.
This describes several different possible implementations, and
some of the trade-offs involved.

Answer (score 0):

From [IBM](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fusers_61.htm)

> Note: Mutex initialization using the PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER does
>   not immediately initialize the mutex. Instead, on first use, the
>   pthread_mutex_lock() or pthread_mutex_trylock() functions branch into
>   a slow path and cause the initialization of the mutex. Because a mutex
>   is not just a simple memory object and requires that some resources be
>   allocated by the system, an attempt to call pthread_mutex_destroy() or
>   pthread_mutex_unlock() on a mutex that was statically initialized
>   using PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALER and was not yet locked causes an EINVAL
>   error.

If you use `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, you do the error checking later.

Comment: So checking errors when calling pthread_mutex_lock(),  pthread_mutex_unlock() and pthread_mutex_destroy() is enough?

Comment: @Pax The Posix standard says that `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is sufficient initialization, and that it cannot fail (because it can be used to initialize static variables in C, which is compile time initialization).  A `pthread_mutex_t` initialized with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZE` is sufficiently initialized for all of the functions which use the `pthread_mutex_t` to have defined behavior, as if the mutex had been initialized with all default values.  Beyond that, you should always verify that the other functions worked as well, regardless of how the mutex was initialized.

Comment: It's not clear whether the link is describing mutexes in AIX or in Linux (IBM supports both), but at any rate, it is describing _one_ particular implementation, not what Posix requires.